# CKEditor : How to load the my own javascript file

Tags: html, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in my web app and new to it. It seems my js file isn't downloading with CKEditor, how to include external js files in CKEditor ?

Comment: What kind of external file did you create? a plugin? or are you trying to overwrite default functionality?

Comment: @Mark: it's plugin,  my js file which is already included in web page, is not working with CKEditor. I think there must be some way to add as we do with css e.g. config.contentsCss = '/myFile.css'; in config.js

Comment: I updated my answer below, you'll have to use `config.exraPlugins` to include the plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration related js needs to be in `config.js`

All plugin related files go in the plugins `plugins/[plugin_name]/plugin.js`
You'll need to add them to the config using extraPlugins `config.extraPlugins: 'plugin',`

If you want to do something else you can just load another .js

for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="customcode.js"></script></code>
```

in customcode.js you can put your eventhandling and overrides

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
{
    alert("CKEditor is loaded");
});
```